# Rails 3 Routing Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Why in Rails 3 do you have to uncomment `match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'` (as seen in this [Hello World article](http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/02/05/hello_rails_3_world/)) to make the index method of the hello controller be called when you go to `http://localhost:3000/hello`? Can somebody please explain why we have to do this in Rails 3 but not Rails 2, and is this a normal thing for Rails 3 or is it some kind of hack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That particular match is sort of a catch-all for any requests that haven't already been defined.

Ideally you should be using [Resource Routing](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default), but that matcher still exists as legacy support.

It's commented out by default because Rails assumes that if a user attempts to access a route that you didn't explicitly define, it should cause a 404 error instead of a 500 error, which is what would happen if I tried to access `http://localhost:3000/hello` with that matcher enabled, because there's no 'hello' controller.

Comment: Is there a danger or security hole of some sorts the catch-all legacy route?